# ExitStatus 2 when I run a command over SSH with JSCH

Tags: java, jsch

I'm trying to run the following command over SSH with JSch :

> AlgoName -m /tmp/input1.txt -f /tmp/input2.txt > /tmp/output.txt

The value of **exitStatus** is **2**. The command does not work over SSH with Jsch but it run successfully on the server.

My code:

```
        ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) s.openChannel("exec");
        channelExec.setCommand(command);         
        channelExec.connect();

        int exitStatus = channelExec.getExitStatus();
        channelExec.disconnect();
```

Comment: Did you try to run it manually through SSH using the same username? It could be a permission issue.

Comment: @jbx Yes, when I connect with the same user on the server, the command works well

Comment: I solved the problem. I posted the solution in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm I'm trying to run is written in Perl, actually when I execute the remote SSH command via JSCH, the user profile used to run the command are not loaded, so the environment variables are not loaded either.

The solution is to load the profile when I run the command, like this:

```
bash -l -c 'AlgoName -m /tmp/input1.txt -f /tmp/input2.txt > /tmp/output.txt'
```